# Git has taken over my Mac

Tags: macos, git

When ever I open terminal it goes to a "git" window and git is running in my activity monitor and about 80% of the cpu.

When ever I force quit it in the activity monitor, it just pop's back up in there. I've even relaunched finder and restarted my computer and git is still in the terminal and activity monitor, it seem unquittable.

How do I stop git running?

Comment: How did you install `git` in the first place? Check which files are open: Go to Activity Monitor, press `cmd`+`I` and see "Open files and ports". Also, are there any related messages in `Console.app`?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK git does none of these things - I suspect you got yourself a Trojan / Virus.
Some things to check:

- what is the output of ps auxw|grep -i git? What's the path returned for git?
- can you remove the git executable / remove the executable bit?

Comment: A virus/trojan on Mac? I know it's certainly possible and they're out there, but should you really assume thats what it is? Not trying to apologize for or defend Apple or anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check for a reference to `git` in your ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc, possibly this was added as part of the install.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the git is somehow part of your prompt display. Look in the shell's initialization files if it is used there.

Of course, normally git for the prompt-displaying call should not take long at all - there might be someting really wrong here.